# Is there a male counterpart of jezebel?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

Jezebel means a shameless or immoral woman.

Is there a connate or coeval word for a man that would mean the same, as if it was coined to be the male counterpart of Jezebel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Jezebel was Queen of Israel when Ahab was King. She is written about in 1 Kings. Her name lives in infamy to this day because of her actions, not because the name was coined intentionally with any implied meaning. I know of no male counterparts whose names carry the same connotation, but *Adolf* and *Benedict* spring to mind as two examples of male names that are closely associated with the notorious actions of particular individuals.

Comment: benedict? what benedict? It's still a popular name here.

Comment: @Matthaeus: [Benedict Arnold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedict_Arnold), a famous traitor.

Comment: @oerkelens This would not work at all in British English. Benedict Arnold was one of the King's subjects, who came to his senses, regretted his foolish past, and realised his loyalty lay with the crown. A hero and lesson to us all that it is never too late to repent.

Answer (score 4):

***Judas*** is a male name widely reserved for opprobrium, not for immoral or shameless behavior but for traitorous behavior. It is a perfectly honorable name that acquired a taint after Judas Iscariot betrayed Jesus. As a biblical name, it has a sort of parallel to the name Jezebel, even though the two characters were separated by several centuries.

Answer (score 2):

A male reprobate is a

> **[Corinthian](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/30331/Corinthian)** 1. a man devoted to the pursuit of pleasure • Syn:
>   ↑**playboy**, ↑**man-about-town**

Comment: Ay, but that is received as a compliment by Hal in [1H4 2.4](http://internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/Annex/Texts/1H4/Q1/scene/2.4): “Tom, Dicke, and Francis, they take it already vpon their saluation, that . . .I am . . . a Corinthian, a lad of metall, a good boy (by the Lord so they call me) and when I am king of England I shall command all the good lads in Eastcheape.” It is the old sexual double standard: Jezebel brings idolatry to Zion, and her name becomes a byword for female wickedness; Solomon brings idolatry to Zion, and his name becomes a by-word for—what?

Answer (score 1):

Jezebel's husband was Ahab, and Captain Ahab (of Herman Melville's [Moby Dick)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moby-Dick) at least, was a reprehensible man. So, as it were, was the original [**Ahab**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahab) who was Jezebel's "partner in crime."

Answer (score 0):

The "male" Jezebel spirit is Hamon. This was shared with me last night... I'm still looking for supporting scripture/documentation.

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE. This seems a bit unfair on [Jane Hamon's husband Tom](http://www.selahministries.co.uk/jane-hamon-cd-sets/192-the-root-of-jezebel.html); but perhaps that existing link could be what you felt was shared with you?

Comment: This would be *Haman*, who like Jezebel persecuted the Jews and came to a sticky end. The story is in the OT Book of Esther: but I am not sure that *jezebel* in normal usage is a religious reference.

Answer (score 0):

I kinda would have to go with the male counterpart of a jezebel could be many things a hustler, player, (at least in Western Society) ..  there is such a double standard when it comes to what a woman can do before being viewed as  a whore or a hussy and what a man can do before it's considered even the least bit shameless.

Answer (score -2):

Jezebel is a spirit....it is neither male nor female. A spirit has no gender they just need a house in this realm to operate. House being a body which can be either male or female. It's characteristics are the same....manipulating, controlling, plots evil ect. I would suggest reading up on the spirit of Jezebel it's easy to identify the spirit when you don't label it my male or female but what it actually is.